# Device: (70:18) TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'articles.map')

Tags: api, react-native, expo

I am trying to fetch the headlines in my react native app but I face the above error. I got the API from this free api website called newsapi.org.
Can somebody please help me?
All I want to do is fetch the headlines and put those into Touchable Opacity. But it's not happening.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, ScrollView, Button} 
from 
'react-native';
import {Header, Icon} from 'react-native-elements';
import { Constants } from 'expo';

import {
createStackNavigator,
createNavigatorContainer 
} from "react-navigation";

const API = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=the-times-of- 
india&apiKey=761cc8b034a4455282afae5902a7c51b';

export default class PendingUpdates extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.state = {
  articles: []
};
}

componentDidMount() {
fetch(API)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => this.setState({ articles: data.articles }));
}

static navigationOptions = {
title: 'PENDING UPDATES',
style:{display:'flex',
flexDirection:'row',
backgroundColor:"#FFD700"}
};
render() {

const { articles } = this.state.articles;

return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    {articles.map(articles =>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.options} key={articles.source.id}>
        <Text href={articles.url}>{articles.title}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )}
  </View>
);

}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
display:'flex',
flexDirection:'column'
},
options:{
flex:1,
alignItems:'center',
borderColor:'#008080'
}

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
const { articles } = this.state;
```

Your `state` is containing `articles` object so you are `destructuring` your `state` and reading variable `articles`. With your code it takes articles is inside articles.

Read [Object Destructuring](https://javascript.info/destructuring-assignment#object-destructuring) for more information on this